# Unable to read properties from application.yml while customizing/overriding ClientRegistrationRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, java-11

I am trying to implement customized client repository as mentioned in this document.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.x/reference/html/jc.html#jc-oauth2login-completely-override-autoconfiguration

As per the documentaion , properties are hardcoded in code , I am trying to read those properties from application.yml. However, properties are not available when it's needed to be set.

**Any pointer how this can be achieved? How to make application.yml properties available here.**

Application.yml:

```
sso:
  enabled: true
  registrationId: myApp
  clientName: myApp
  .....
```

POJO corresponding to sso properties

```
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties("sso")
public class SsoPropertiesConfig {
    private boolean enabled;
    private String clientName;
    private String registrationId;
    ....
```

Websecurity Configuration

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class OAuth2LoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    SsoPropertiesConfig ssoPropertiesConfig = new SsoPropertiesConfig();

    private final PasswordResolver passwordResolver;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login();
    }


    @Bean
    public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.myClientRegistration());
    }

    private ClientRegistration myClientRegistration() {
        log.info("ssoPropertiesConfig :{}",ssoPropertiesConfig);
```

> // all properties of ssoPropertiesConfig are coming as NULL

```
        return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(ssoPropertiesConfig.getRegistrationId())
                .clientName(ssoPropertiesConfig.getClientName())
                ....
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are creating the properties yourself using `new` and not letting spring manage them using dependency injection.

your code:

```
SsoPropertiesConfig ssoPropertiesConfig = new SsoPropertiesConfig();
```

You can just remove the `new` declaration since you have annotated your class with `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

so just keep:

```
private SsoPropertiesConfig ssoPropertiesConfig;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to inject the SsoPropertiesConfig where you want to use it, but instead you create it like a POJO not  a Spring bean.

You can use an @Autowired annotation like this

```
@Autowired
SsoPropertiesConfig ssoPropertiesConfig;
```

Or simply as you have a requires arguments constructor you can have it as a final field:

```
   private final  SsoPropertiesConfig ssoPropertiesConfig;
```

Note: You must use final.